# Move Worksheet based off a cell value to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, automation, worksheet

I'm hoping someone can help with this but I'm having the darnest time getting anything to work.
I have a rather large workbook with lots of worksheets, I have a report that runs and populates Column B with a "trigger"
Column A: is the name of all the worksheets in the workbook. Column B is the indicator that the specific worksheet needs to be moved, e.g. "Yes". I need to move the specified workbook into another workbook.

I can only find applicable examples for moving cells but it didn't work. Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated!

```
Dim WBK As Workbook
Dim WBK2 As Workbook 
Set WBK= ThisWorkbook
Set WBK= Workbooks.Open(Filename:"ReportList.xlsx") 
For i = 1 To Sheets("MoveSheet").End(xlDown).Row '(ERRORHERE)
   If Sheets("MoveSheet").Range("B" & i) = "Move" Then 
       Sheets(Sheets("MoveSHeet").Range("A" & i)).Move After:=wkbk2.Sheets(1)
   Else
 End if
Next i 
End Sub
```

Comment: Which specific part of this is giving you problems?

Comment: @TimWilliams I've updated the description! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted code is not too far off - a few typos etc

Try this:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsList As Worksheet, c As Range
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsList = wb.Worksheets("MoveSheet") 'your sheet with tab names and "Move" flag
    
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Example\Path\ReportList.xlsx") 'provide the full path
    
    For Each c In wsList.Range("A1:A" & wsList.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        If c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Move" Then  'has a flag to be moved?
            wb.Worksheets(c.Value).Move after:=wbDest.Sheets(wbDest.Sheets.Count) 'move after last sheet
        End If
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a for each loop would be good.

```
Dim wkbk1 As Workbook - Main workbook
Dim wkbk2 As Workbook - Your other workbook

Set wkbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set wkbk2 = "input name here" 

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In wkbk1.Sheets

'use if code to check if certain Criteria met' 
ws.Move wkbk2.Sheets(Sheets.Count)

Next ws
```

Comment: HI Matt! Thank you but it didn't seem to work for me, I set my condition as "If wkbk1.Range("D2").Value = Worksheet.Name then wroksheet.Copy Before: wkbk2.Sheets(1). I guess it should loop through the column that triggers if the worksheet should be moved but I just can't get it to do that

Answer (score 0):

I would have one loop to run through column A and check if the sheet needs to be move by checking the column B right alongside it. If column B contains the trigger, which would be checked with a if condition, then move the sheet to another workbook.

For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

If Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i) = "Yes" Then

Sheets(Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i)).Move After:=Workbooks("Otherworkbook.xls").Sheets(1)

Else

End If

Next i

Something like this but might need to declare the second workbook with the full filename and directory.

Comment: I'm getting a "subscript out of range" error with "For i = i To Sheets("ToMove").End(xlDown).Row

Comment: Oh yeah you have to add the range to start from, e.g. i=1 to Sheets("ToMove").Range("A1").End(xlDown)